# How should we tag Incredibles 2?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

The new tag [incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredibles-2) has been created to tag a few questions about the new film. There is an already existing tag [the-incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredibles-2) that follows the naming convention of [the-incredibles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredibles) from the first film.

I've swapped the tags on the questions to the older, format matching tag, but I don't know how to clean up the duplicate. Tag synonyms is my next privilege, but I don't believe it's appropriate here presumably only one of the tags should exist.

Oh and I've just realised the film name doesn't actually keep the "The" convention from the first film. My bad.

Still one of these tags should probably be removed.

Comment: This is a good place for tag synonyms, unfortunately one needs to have 5 score (or be a moderator) to suggest them. I'm sorry for the spoilers this led you to, that was not my intention. But yes, the film is _Incredibles 2_ and not _The Incredibles 2_, hence my change.

Comment: @Edlothiad that's fine. The spoilers weren't really a problem, I was more curious as to why the ignore didn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main tag has been selected as [incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredibles-2) with [the-incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredibles-2) as a synonym of it now.

---

The film is called *"Incredibles 2"* not *"The Incredibles 2"* so we should be using the [incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredibles-2) tag. And for what it's worth I have rolled back your tag edits for this reason.

[image: Incredibles 2 poster]

As for if a synonym is appropriate in this case, I would assume so to avoid cases like these. However, you need 5 score in a tag to do so, therefore it would be best to ask a moderator to do so. I.e. make [the-incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredibles-2) a synonym of [incredibles-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredibles-2).

A synonym proposal has been [created](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/incredibles-2/synonyms), however, you will need 5 score in the tag to be able to vote on it.

---

It's worth pointing out as well that [tags autodelete after 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279921/345161) if they are no longer used on any questions.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too late after looking through more internet information. Sorry about the mixup. It was caused by me seeing Questions with the new tag after I'd put the older one on ignore.

Comment: @Jontia No worries mistakes happen, especially if you aren't too familiar with a work.